Lower bound in the singularity of random Bernoulli matrices
Let $A_n$ be a random $n \times n$ matrix with entries in $\{-1, +1\}$. As usual, "random" here means with respect to the uniform measure over such matrices.
The strong version of the singularity conjecture is that, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\mathbb{P}\{ \text{det}(A_n) = 0\} = (1 +o(1)) \, n^2 2^{-(n-1)}
$$
I understand the right hand side comes from the fact that there are $2 \binom{n}{2} \sim n^2 $ possible selections of rows and columns and that $2^{-(n-1)}$ is the probability that any such pair is equal up to sign.
However, this is not a rigorous argument, since it ignores the dependence of such selections of rows and columns. Is there a rigorous lower bound that matches the asymptotics above that handles the dependence issues?

Shouldn't it be trivial to make that lower bound rigorous? The probability three rows are the same is like $2^{-2n}$...

On the singularity of random Bernoulli matrices - novel integer partitions and lower bound expansions
 derives the lower bound (theorem 1)
$$\mathbb{P}\{ \text{det}(A_n) = 0\} \geq    2^{2-n} \binom{n}{2}-2^{-2n} \left(12 \binom{n}{2}^2-4 \binom{n}{2}\right),$$
which is of order $n^2 2^{1-n}$ for $n\rightarrow\infty$. The "independent selection" contribution is the first term $2^{2-n} \binom{n}{2}$. The second term is smaller by a factor $n^2/2^n$ for large $n$.

Yeah, I saw this paper. I guess their interest is in deriving an even sharper asymptotic expansion. However, I was wondering if there are any elementary arguments that lead to the leading order term (at least as a lower bound, obviously we can't expect this for the upper bound, otherwise we'd solve the strong conjecture)

The earlier comment gives the elementary argument you're looking for: for any pair, let $E_{i,j}$ be the event that the $i$th and $j$th rows are equal up to signs. Then a lower bound for $\mathbb P(\bigcup_{i<j}E_{i,j})$ is a lower bound for $\mathbb P(\det(A_n)=0)$. You can get a lower bound from the sum of the first two terms of inclusion-exclusion. The contributions to the second term are of the form $E_{i,j}\cap E_{i',j'}$. If $i,i',j,j'$ are distinct, this probability is $2^{-2(n-1)}$. If one of $i',j'$ agrees with one of $i,j$, it's also $2^{-2(n-1)}$. Now sum over $n^4$ many terms.

Thanks. The inclusion-exclusion argument is obvious in retrospect, makes sense!

My interest was in deriving an even sharper asymptotic expansion.
